# How can I load an HTML file using Flex StageView?

Tags: html, flexbuilder, flex4.5

I want to display a HTML file for a mobile application using Flex Builder 4.5.

The following code does not work -

```
      protected var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
      protected function view1_viewActivateHandler():void
   {
      if (StageWebView.isSupported)
    {
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(5, 80, stage.width-10, stage.height-9);
    webView.stage = this.stage;
            webView.loadURL("file:/assets/sample.html");   
                ......
```

I get this error - Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=Load error.

I am new to actionscript and flex.

Answer (score 1):

The html file cannot be loaded using  `webView.loadURL("file:/assets/sample.html");`

I found the reason and workaround [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3443946#3443946)